# Reading text file into JTable JAVA for inventory system

Tags: java

Just starting to learn about JTable and I have a JButton that saves the contents of a JTable into a text file vertically. How can I write back the text file into the JTable?

The table has 4 columns (ex. ItemName | Description | Category | Date added). When each row is saved into the text file, it's saved vertically like a list.

I've tried saving the contents horizontally however this becomes a problem when the specific cell contains more than one word. (ex. saving "SD Card" from ItemName becomes "SD" in ItemName and "Card" in Description after reading the textfile basically shifting everything to the right)

```
 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
           BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

           for(int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){//rows
                 for(int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++){//columns
                 bw.write(table.getValueAt(i, j).toString()+"\n");
                        }
                        bw.newLine();
                    }

                    bw.close();
                    fw.close();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(AddItem.class.getName(), null).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }t(i, j).toString()+"\n");
                        }
                        bw.newLine();
                    }

                    bw.close();
                    fw.close();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(AddItem.class.getName(), null).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
```

The code i've tried using is this however it isnt working.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
            row = lines[i].toString().split(" ");

            for(int j = 0; j < (row.length/4); j=j+4) {
                   model.addRow(new Object [] {row [j], row[j+1], row [j+2], row [j+3]});

                            }
                        }
```

Comment: *saving "SD Card" from ItemName becomes "SD" in ItemName and "Card" in Description after reading the textfile* This is simply because you chose an empty space as column delimiter. A simple solution might be using a different delimiter such as ";" in both saving and reading operations like if it was CSV file.

Comment: that helped thanks!